# Get build duration using post-build Groovy script (Jenkins/Hudson)

Tags: groovy, jenkins, hudson

I have a post build script and am trying to get the build duration. I am trying to get it like so:

```
def build = manager.build
build.duration.toString()
```

but that just yields 0. Is there a way I can get the build duration using a post build groovy script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While a build is still running, the duration has not yet been set. Use [`Run.getDurationString()`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getDurationString%28%29) instead, or get the current duration from the difference between [`Run.getTimeInMillis()`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29) and `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: how would I implement the Run.getDurationString()? Im having trouble figure out how to implement it

Comment: heinst: `build` is a `Run`, so just call `build.durationString`.